# why TSX file is reading the conditions like a normal text? how to check using if else condition over TSX file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-parts, spfx

I just want to test to validate using If... else if condition

Here is the peace of code to test the condition, mylists.Title returns the SP lists,

```
if({mylists.Title} === {'Documents'})
  {
    <span>{'Good morning'}</span>
  } else 
  {
    <span>{'Good Evening'}</span>
  }
```

but its considering like a normal text
[image]

I know that i am just checking very simple condition only but really don`t understand here why its considering as normal string

Please assist me here how to validate using if ...else if condition over TSX file

Comment: Even i tested with == `if({mylists.Title} == {'Documents'})` but still its considering as normal text

Comment: Check the docs regarding conditional rendering https://react.dev/learn/conditional-rendering